# Sylius: adding resource with translateable content

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, resourcebundle, sylius

I am building an app based on Sylius standard edition. With the ResourceBundle i handled to integrate my own entities and the corresponding relations. This new resources should be related later to the products entity, but first i want to get it working "standalone". The backend works for both, the added resource and for relations. These are editable via form-collections. Very fine! Now i want to get translated database-content for my new resource. I tried the way i did it in Symfony earlier, but it didn't work. The last vew days i tried every possible solution found, but none of this works, or i made mistakes... Neither the translation-tables where constructed when typing:

```
app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

nor translatable content is visible in the forms. When calling the edit action, i get following error:

```
error:
Neither the property "translations" nor one of the methods "getTranslations()", "translations()", "isTranslations()", "hasTranslations()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "KontaktBundle\Entity\Kontakte".
```

Is somebody out there with an example implementation of a extended Sylius-resource with translateable database-content? I'm still learning symfony and sylius too, can you tell me what i'm missing or doing wrong?

### Many Thanks to @gvf. Now i figured out that the config entry must be set. This gave me a functional example which i want to provide here:

### Configs

```
# app/config/sylius_config.yml (must be imported in config)

# Adding Resource
sylius_resource:
    # Resource Settings
    settings:
        sortable: true
        paginate: 50
        allowed_paginate: [50, 100, 500]
        filterable: true

    resources:
        dbk.authors:
            driver: doctrine/orm
            templates: AuthorBundle:Backend
            object_manager: default
            classes:
                model: AuthorBundle\Entity\Kontakte
                #interface: // if you have an interface configured
                controller: Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Controller\ResourceController
                repository: Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
                translation:
                    model: AuthorBundle\Entity\AuthorsTranslation
                    mapping:
                        fields: ['anrede','biografie']
```

### Services

```
# app/config/sylius_services.yml (must be imported in config)
parameters:
    # Parameter for our author entity
    app.form.type.authors.class: AuthorBundle\Form\AuthorsType
    app.form.type.authors_translation.class: AuthorBundle\Form\AuthorsTranslationType

services:
    # Adding Authors Backend menu Item
    dbk_backend_authors.menu_builder:
        class: AuthorBundle\EventListener\MenuBuilderListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: sylius.menu_builder.backend.main, method: addBackendMenuItems }
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: sylius.menu_builder.backend.sidebar, method: addBackendMenuItems }

    # Adding Authors FormType
    app.form.type.authors:
        class: "%app.form.type.authors.class%"
        tags: 
            - {name: form.type, alias: dbk_authors }

    app.form.type.authors_translation:
        class: "%app.form.type.authors_translation.class%"
        tags: 
            - {name: form.type, alias: dbk_authors_translation }
```

### EventListener (Adds Menu Entry in Sylius-Backend)

```
<?php

// AuthorBundle/EventListener/MenuBuilderListener/MenuBuilderListener.php

namespace AuthorBundle\EventListener;

use Sylius\Bundle\WebBundle\Event\MenuBuilderEvent;

class MenuBuilderListener
{
    public function addBackendMenuItems(MenuBuilderEvent $event)
    {
        $menu = $event->getMenu();

        $menu['assortment']->addChild('vendor', array(
            'route' => 'Authors',
            'labelAttributes' => array('icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-user'),
        ))->setLabel('Authors');
    }
}
```

### Entities

#### Authors (The new resource hich we want to add and to translate)

```
<?php

// AuthorBundle/Entity/Authors.php

namespace AuthorBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Sylius\Component\Translation\Model\AbstractTranslatable;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Authors
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="authors")
 */
class Authors extends AbstractTranslatable
{

    //
    // IDENTIFIER FIELDS
    //

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="bigint", length=20, nullable=false, options={"unsigned":"true"})
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;


    //
    // FIELDS
    //

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="vorname", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $vorname;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nachname", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nachname;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    //
    // TranslationFields - Getters and Setters
    //

    /**
     * Get Anrede
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAnrede()
    {
        return $this->translate()->getAnrede();
    }

    /**
     * Set Anrede
     *
     * @param string $anrede
     *
     * @return Authors
     */
    public function setAnrede($anrede)
    {
        $this->translate()->setAnrede($anrede);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get Biografie
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBiografie()
    {
        return $this->translate()->getBiografie();
    }

    /**
     * Set Biografie
     *
     * @param string $biografie
     *
     * @return Authors
     */
    public function setBiografie($biografie)
    {
        $this->translate()->setBiografie($biografie);
        return $this;
    }


    //
    // Getters and Setters
    //

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }


    /**
     * Set vorname
     *
     * @param string $vorname
     *
     * @return Authors
     */
    public function setVorname($vorname)
    {
        $this->vorname = $vorname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get vorname
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getVorname()
    {
        return $this->vorname;
    }

    /**
     * Set nachname
     *
     * @param string $nachname
     *
     * @return Authors
     */
    public function setNachname($nachname)
    {
        $this->nachname = $nachname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nachname
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getNachname()
    {
        return $this->nachname;
    }


    public function  __toString(){
        return $this->getFullName();
    }

}
```

#### AuthorsTranslation (This is the Entity for tanslation of Authors)

```
<?php

// AuthorBundle/Entity/AuthorsTranslation.php

namespace AuthorBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Sylius\Component\Translation\Model\AbstractTranslation;

/**
 * AuthorsTranslation
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="authors_translation")
 */
class AuthorsTranslation extends AbstractTranslation
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="bigint", length=20, nullable=false, options={"unsigned":"true"})
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    //
    // TRANSLATABLE - FIELDS
    //

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="anrede", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $anrede;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="biografie", type="text")
     */
    private $biografie;

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    //
    // GETTERS AND SETTERS
    //

    /**
     * Set anrede
     *
     * @param string $anrede
     * @return Authors
     */
    public function setAnrede($anrede)
    {
        $this->anrede = $anrede;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get anrede
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAnrede()
    {
        return $this->anrede;
    }


    /**
     * Set biografie
     *
     * @param string $biografie
     *
     * @return Authors
     */
    public function setBiografie($biografie)
    {
        $this->biografie = $biografie;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get biografie
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBiografie()
    {
        return $this->biografie;
    }



}
```

### FormTypes

#### AuthorsType

```
<?php

// AuthorBundle/Form/AuthorsType.php

namespace AuthorBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder;

class AuthorsType extends AbstractType
{

     /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            // Add Translations to Form.
            ->add('translations', 'a2lix_translations', array(
                'required' => false,
                'fields' => array(
                    'anrede' => array(
                        'label' => 'Anrede',
                    ),
                    'biografie' => array(
                        'label' => 'Biografie',
                        'attr' => array('data-edit' => 'wysiwyg', 'rows' => '15'),
                        'required' => false,
                    )
                )
            ))

            ->add('vorname', null, array(
                'label' => 'Vorname',
                'required' => false,
            ))

            ->add('nachname', null, array(
                'label' => 'Nachname',
                'required' => false,
            ))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
            $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'csrf_protection'   => false,
                'data_class' => 'AuthorBundle\Entity\Authors'
            ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'dbk_authors';
    }
}
```

#### AuthorsTranslationType

```
<?php

// AuthorBundle/Form/AuthorsTranslationType.php

namespace AuthorBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class AuthorsTranslationType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('anrede', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'Anrede'
            ))
            ->add('biografie', 'textarea', array(
                'label' => 'Biografie'
            ))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'dbk_authors_translation';
    }
}
```

### Form Template

```
{# AuthorBundle/Resources/views/backend/edit||add.html.twig - as you like... the call of form.translation (line 5) is the point here #}
{% form_theme form 'SyliusWebBundle:Backend:forms.html.twig' %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        {{ form_row(form.translations, {'attr': {'class': 'input-lg'}}) }}
        {{ form_row(form.vorname) }}
        {{ form_row(form.nachname) }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: UPDATE - In 1.0.0-alpha `translation` field is not under `classes` anymore. In this example, it should be directly under `dbk.contact`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the Product and `ProductTranslation` under the models folder in Sylius Components to see an example of how Sylius implements it.

`Kontakte` needs to extend `AbstractTranslatable`, you also need to create a class `KontakteTranslation` that extends `AbstractTranslation`. Under `sylius_resource` you also need to configure the translations:

```
sylius_resource:
resources:
    dbk.contact:
        driver: doctrine/orm
        templates: KontaktBundle:Backend
        object_manager: default
        classes:
            model: KontaktBundle\Entity\Kontakte
            controller: Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Controller\ResourceController
            repository: Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
            translation:
                model: KontaktBundle\Entity\KontakteTranslation
                mapping:
                    fields: {...fields that will be translated...}
```

Get rid of gedmo translatable extension because Sylius doesn't use it.

Comment: Thank you! The translation entry in config was the part which i didn't know. I searched the products but didn'd find such an config there. All other things i had tryed before.

Comment: It's in `Sylius\Bundle\ProductBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration`. Not obvious though!

Comment: Thank you again. I edited my initial post and put in a functional example, maybe that helps other people :)

Comment: UPDATE - In 1.0.0-alpha `translation` field is not under `classes` anymore. In this example, it should be directly under `dbk.contact`